# Excel 2010 VBA save, open location, select file

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have made a VBA macro to save a file as xlsx and pdf, at a set location with a filename taken from a cell in the sheet, after which the save location opens.

Code as follows:

```
Sub SaveAs()

Dim FName           As String
Dim FPath           As String

FPath = "PATHNAME HERE"
FName = Sheets("SHEETNAME").Range("E1").Text
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName, FileFormat:=51

ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=FPath & "\" & FName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard

Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & "PATHNAME HERE", vbNormalFocus    

End Sub
```

However the folder i am saving those files becomes quite filled, and for easy access i want to open the path in explorer with the just saved pdf selected (as in, I want to open folder with the file selected, not like opening the pdf). Any suggestions how to accomplish this?

Comment: You say you are successfully saving the files, and the issue is how to open explorer with the recently saved filepath in the address bar?

Comment: Basically all I have now works fine, but i would like to add functionality to have the latest PDF selected (the one created by the same macro) when opening the folder in explorer.

Comment: I would suggest you create a String variable called FileNPath where `FileNPath = FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf"`  Then include that string from your call to explorer.  The solution provided below by @katz accomplishes this, when using the full path.

Comment: I have tried this ( where it becomes   `Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & FileNPath, vbNormalFocus` ) but this actually opens the pdf file. I would like to just have it selected in the opened folder.

Comment: Ahhhgg..  I see.  Your question might need reworded.  "and for easy access i want to open the path in explorer with the just saved pdf selected" gives the impression to me and @katz apparently that you want to OPEN the file selected in the path, as opposed to Opening Explorer.exe and selecting the file without opening the PDF itself.

Comment: added info, sorry for confusing you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Use

```
Shell "explorer.exe /select," & FPath & "\" & FName, vbMaximizedFocus
```

instead of

```
Shell "explorer.exe" & " " & "PATHNAME HERE", vbNormalFocus
```

Comment: I could do that, but that won't add the functionality I would like, namely selecting the just created PDF file. Also it breaks the functionality (variable not defined).

Comment: Thanks, got it working with some minor adjustments:  `PathNName = FPath & "\" & FName & ".pdf"
     
    Shell "explorer.exe /select," & PathNName, vbMaximizedFocus`